# Probability of unfair coin not giving 2 heads

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, mathematical-modeling, independence

**Problem:** An unfair coin with probability $p$ to flip **Tails** is flipped 4 times independently. What is the probability of no **Heads** twice in a row?

**My answer:** I calculated the probability that of the event

$$A = \text{Heads twice in a row}$$

by splitting it into the three events

$$A_i = \text{i Heads, Heads twice in a row}$$

, took the complement and got:

$\mathbb{P}(A^c) = 1- 3p^2(1-p)^2 - 4p(1-p)^3 - (1-p)^4$

Is there a quicker way to derive the answer?

Comment: I think the third term is missing a factor of $p$. The counts look correct to me.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik Thank you. I fixed it. As Neal pointed out I missed a factor of $p$ in the third term. Do you still need more detail?

Comment: @user7802048 No.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flipping 4x with no heads twice in a row means either you had 2 heads separated by at least one tail, or 1 head, or no heads. (This is because if you had 3 or 4 heads with 4 coins, you must have had at least 2 in a row.)

So break this down:

- 2 heads (but no consecutive heads). There are 3 configurations (HTHT, HTTH, THTH). Each has probability $p^2(1-p)^2$.
- 1 head: There are four configurations, each has probability $p^3(1-p)$.
- No heads: There is one configuration, with probability $p^4$.

Add these up and you get
$$ 3p^2(1-p)^2 + 4p^3(1-p) + p^4 $$

Edit- Your approach is also correct, though you could stand to show your work :) You can verify this by expanding these polynomials in $p$ and showing that they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution appears to be correct, but ill suggest my own interpretation and you'll be the judge.

The probability to have $HHTT$ is obviously $(1-p)(1-p)(p)(p)$ and there is 3 ways to permute $HHTT$ (those being $HHTT$, $THHT$, and $TTHH$) so the probability of $P(two-heads- in-a-row)$ is $3*(1-p)^2p^2$ the compliment of this being $1-3(1-p)^2p^2$

Comment: You’ve undercounted. If you get three or four heads, that also gives you two heads in a row.

Comment: Ah thanks, didn't consider it since the expected value is 2 for each